# How to add object having 4 attributes in array in java

Tags: java

```
Object[] Flights = new Object[10];
```

This is an Object array, now what i want is to add 4 attributes to each object which includes String and integer?

How can  I do this ?

Comment: You need to create your own custom class that has the 4 attributes you want and then make an array of that rather than an array of `Object`.

Comment: You should start with https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/prog-140388.html

Comment: If you're using Java 14, you can use a record, which is a simple class that just contains data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom class and define the attribute that you want

```
public class Solution {

  static class CustomObj {
     int id;
     String name;
     // your properties
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       CustomObj[] objsC = new CustomObj[10];
       // your logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do this in `Java`, you absolutely need to create a class.

```
 public class Myclass {
      public String myString;
      public int myInteger;

 }
```

and create an instance of that class :

```
public mainClass {
   public void main(String args[]){

    MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
    myInstance.myString = "the value you want";
    myInstance.myInteger = 1;
 }
}
```